# Jquery onchange event not triggered

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

I have a drop down list inside a data grid in main page and upon changing values it should display popup and popup values are posted back to the main page.  I have to trigger onchange event which is not working.

Below is the code I am using.

Server side:

```
ddlID.Attributes.Add("OnChange", "return Show("txtFName.text,txtLstName.text");
```

Client side:

```
$('#ddlID').val(6).trigger("change"); //should hit function  Show() which is not triggered.
```

Comment: Show us your HTML, and we could help you.

Comment: provide demo that replicates problem. We don't know what `Add()` does

Comment: As Wilfredo said, seeing the generated HTML would help. It is likely that the generated id for the element does not match the id you are putting in your javascript, as [.NET changes element ids](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/699677/net-changes-the-element-ids). I recommend using classes to access elements instead of ids in .NET projects whenever possible because of this.

Comment: <select name="dgLS$ctl07$ddlID" id="dgLS_ctl07_ddlID" onchange="return Show('txtFName.text,txtLstName.text')">
   <option value="6^FirstName">First Name</option>
   <option value="3^LastName">Last Name</option>
   <option selected="selected" value="">none selected</option>

  </select>
   <option value="6^FirstName">First Name</option>
   <option value="3^LastName">Last Name</option>
   <option selected="selected" value="">none selected</option>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I figured out. The control is inside data grid and when I am using the ID directly via jquery ($('#ddlID')), it is not working. I have to get the client side ID using $(""#"+ddlID.ClientID+"""). Also we can use class selector. I am triggering on change using a external js file.